# Imgur API image search not returning data

Tags: javascript, imgur

I'm trying to write an app using Node.js and Express.js (I'm working through the Free Code Camp curriculum, if that's useful information) that takes in a search term and sends and inquiry to the Imgur API and report back some data about images related to the search term. I've registered my application and received the necessary Client-ID and have included a header per the documentation here and am getting a statusCode of 200 from Imgur, but instead of any "data", I'm getting a number of other properties in the returned object that are not useful. What do I need to do to get image data from Imgur based on a search term?

The URL I'm sending the request to:
`https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/search/{search term}`
per the documentation here: https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/gallery#gallery-search. The response is not in the format described

Search function:

```
this.askImgur = function(req, res) {
  var img_data;
  console.log('askImgur function firing');
  var search_term = url.parse(req.originalUrl||req.path).query;
  console.log(search_term);
  var search_path = path + search_term;//PLUS PAGE

  var options = {
    protocol: "https:",
    host:'api.imgur.com',
    path:search_path,
    method:'GET',
    headers: {
    "Authorization":"Client-ID <CLIENT ID HERE>"
    }
  };

var ds;
  https.get(options, function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
    for (var key in res) {
      if (res.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key);
      }
    }
  }).on('data', function(chunk){
    ds+=chunk;
    console.log("chunk is "+chunk);//does nothing
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
  });
  console.log("ds is "+ds);//does nothing
  //res.json("askImgur function is sending you words");
  res.send(search_term);
};//askImgur function
```

The output:

`Got response: 200
    _readableState
    readable
    domain
    _events
    _eventsCount
    _maxListeners
    socket
    connection
    httpVersionMajor
    httpVersionMinor
    httpVersion
    complete
    headers
    rawHeaders
    trailers
    rawTrailers
    upgrade
    url
    method
    statusCode
    statusMessage
    client
    _consuming
    _dumped
    req`

Based on the documentation, the image data should be in a "data" property, is not returned with the above properties.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this url,

```
https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/search?q={search term}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `node-fetch`, I personally find the API of it a lot easier to use. So go ahead and `npm i node-fetch`.
Then try the code below:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")

const term = "lolcat"
const url = `https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/search/top/1/?q=${term}`
const IMGUR_API_CLIENT = "111111" // your client api

fetch(url, {headers: {Authorization: `Client-ID ${IMGUR_API_CLIENT}`}})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

I hope that helps. Sorry if it's too late.

Answer (score 0):

```
private OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
.url("https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/hot/viral/0.json")
.method("GET", null)
.addHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID <<client_id>>")
.build();
```

Replace << client_id >> with your 15 character Client ID.

Eg: `".addHeader(Authorization", "Client-ID a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h")`